Problem with dimensions in Multi-Output GP GPy.kern.Coregionalize
My training data has dimensions
print(xTrain.shape)
print(yTrain.shape)

(3000, 10)
(3000, 141)

I coregionalize as follows:
ker = GPy.kern.Matern32(10, ARD=True)**GPy.kern.Coregionalize(10,output_dim=141)
m = GPy.models.GPRegression(xTrain, np.reshape(yTrain, (-1,1)), ker, noise_var= 1e-8)

And I get the following error
IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 10

I want to train a GP with 10 inputs and 141 outputs, what am I doing wrong?
